# CarouselView ScrollTo workaround on bug

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I am using a `CarouselView` and a `Timer` to have it make the changing effect every X seconds.
Now as I am finding out there are a few bugs. `ScrollTo` doesn't really scroll the `CarouselView` to the position asked. Setting the `Position property` doesn't help neither.
They will just scroll the position to higher or lower than the current position depending on the parameter sent.

Here is the `C#` for any testing:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), () =>
                {
                    slidePosition++;
                    if (slidePosition == (CarouselView1.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<LinksHeaderTitles>).Count - 1)
                    {
                        for (int i = slidePosition - 2; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            CarouselView1.ScrollTo(0, animate: false);
                        }
                        slidePosition = 0;
                    }
                    CarouselView1.ScrollTo(slidePosition);
                    return true;
                });
```

Is there any better workaround to reseting the position to 0 after the last item was reached?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a try with **[ScrollToPosition.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.scrolltoposition)** :

```
CarouselView1.ScrollTo(slidePosition, position: ScrollToPosition.Start);
```

Maybe it will show what your needs.